# How do I generate a valid arkose_token to create GPT-4 conversations?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

For context, I am trying to build a Chrome extension popup that allows users to chat with ChatGPT on any web page and I am struggling to figure out how I can generate the `arkose_token` that is required within the request payload for creating GPT-4 conversations.

The endpoint  I am trying to call is: `https://chat.openai.com/backend-api/conversation` (POST)

I will be using the current ChatGPT web session to authenticate the request and I just need to find a way to pass a valid arkose token, here is an example payload:

```json
{
    "action": ... ,
    "messages": ... ,
    "parent_message_id": ... ,
    "model": "gpt-4",
    "timezone_offset_min": ... ,
    "suggestions": ... ,
    "history_and_training_disabled": ... ,
    "arkose_token": NEED TO PASS A VALID TOKEN HERE,
    "force_paragen": ...
}
```

I have explored these GitHub repos but I'm not quite sure on how to integrate them into my Chrome extension project:

- https://github.com/noahcoolboy/funcaptcha

  - not supported within a browser environement
- https://github.com/acheong08/arkose-generator

  - ran the script locally and it returns a `bda` value, I am not too sure what to do with this

I know this can be done because there are existing extensions that allow you to use your ChatGPT account and chat with the GPT-4 model with no issues, for example:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/harpa-ai-automation-agent/eanggfilgoajaocelnaflolkadkeghjp?hl=en-GB&authuser=1

Has anyone else faced these issues or have any experience with this? I'm unsure of the best workflows/handling of these arkose tokens.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you run the script locally? I'm trying to retrieve a bda token too.

Answer (score 2):

Use this script to generate an arokse_token:

https://github.com/linweiyuan/chatgpt-arkose-token-api

Clone it, install go and run it using `go run main.go`. It will create a new http service at the mentioned port.

Go to `localhost:port` and click the button. It will display a token.

Comment: Is there nodejs or python version this available?

Comment: The above scripts perfectly for in order to deploy this token generator online can we get nodejs or python version of it?

Comment: there's actually a go version that is really good. https://github.com/acheong08/funcaptcha. Unfortunately, there is no python version (which i am searching for too). But there are many js versions available.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for a chrome extension, so javascript client-side, would this be possible? some code that could help me somewhere?